# How do I open a password-protected PDF with applescript?

Tags: pdf, applescript

I need a little applescript to open a password-protected pdf.

I can't figure out how to access the password text field.

The code I've got :

```
set elPdf to ("Path:to:my:file.pdf")
activate application "Preview"

tell application "Preview"
    open elPdf
    delay 1
    tell application "System Events"
        set value of text field 1 to "password"
        keystroke return
    end tell
end tell
```

Applescript is not finding the text/password field, even when I add "sheet 1" and "window 1"

How to I access the password field of a preview.app pdf with applescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try to access password input via menu bar:

```
set myFolder to path to desktop as string
set myFile to myFolder & "trial.pdf"

tell application "Preview"
  open myFile
  activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
  tell process "Preview"
    tell menu bar 1
      tell menu bar item "File"
        tell menu "File"
          click menu item 13
          keystroke "34ue8XD5mM"
          keystroke return
        end tell
      end tell
    end tell
  end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Wtf? how d'you guess my password? ;-) Worked great. Now how do I prevent Preview from wantint to export my pdf...